# C++ : B-Tree in C++20 (+Iterator support)

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++20

I wrote a B-Tree implementation in C++20, based on my previous Red-Black Tree implementation.

Unit Test Demo : https://wandbox.org/permlink/Brw6TgAhdy89OIyj

Any feedback will be welcomed!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <std::ranges::random_access_range R>
auto range_from(R&& r, int t) {
    return std::ranges::subrange(std::begin(r) + t, std::end(r));
}

template <typename T>
concept Key = std::regular<T> && std::totally_ordered<T>;

template <Key T, std::size_t t, std::predicate<T, T> Comp = std::less<T>>
class BTree {
    static_assert(t >= 2);
    class Node {
        std::size_t n = 0;
        bool leaf = true;
        Node* parent = nullptr;
        std::size_t index = 0;
        std::vector<T> key;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> child;
    public:
        // modifying n must be done only with setN,
        // for the invariants key.size() == n and child.size() == n + 1 (if exists)
        void setN(std::size_t N) {
            n = N;
            key.resize(n);
            if (!leaf) {
                child.resize(n + 1);
            }
        }

        void validateChild() {
            if (leaf) {
                return;
            }
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
                child[i]->index = i;
                child[i]->parent = this;
            }
        }

        [[nodiscard]] std::size_t getN() const {
            return n;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] bool isFull() const {
            return n == 2 * t - 1;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] bool canTakeKey() const {
            return n > t - 1;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] bool hasMinimalKeys() const {
            return n == t - 1;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] bool isEmpty() const {
            return n == 0;
        }

        friend class BTree;

        Node* RightmostLeaf() {
            Node* curr = this;
            while (!curr->leaf) {
                curr = curr->child.back().get();
            }
            return curr;
        }

        Node* LeftmostLeaf() {
            Node* curr = this;
            while (!curr->leaf) {
                curr = curr->child.front().get();
            }
            return curr;
        }

        // merge child[i + 1] and key[i] into child[i]
        void Merge(std::size_t i) noexcept {
            assert(!leaf && child[i]->hasMinimalKeys() && child[i + 1]->hasMinimalKeys());
            child[i]->setN(2 * t - 1);
            child[i]->key[t - 1] = key[i];
            // bring keys of child[i + 1]
            std::ranges::move(child[i + 1]->key, child[i]->key.begin() + t);
            // bring children of child[i + 1]
            if (!child[i]->leaf) {
                std::ranges::move(child[i + 1]->child, child[i]->child.begin() + t);
            }
            // shift children from i + 1 left by 1 (because child[i + 1] is merged)
            std::shift_left(child.begin() + i + 1, child.end(), 1);
            // shift keys from i left by 1 (because key[i] is merged)
            std::shift_left(key.begin() + i, key.end(), 1);
            setN(n - 1);
            validateChild();
            child[i]->validateChild();
        }

        void LeftRotate() noexcept {
            assert(index + 1 < parent->child.size());
            auto sibling = parent->child[index + 1].get();
            // left rotation
            setN(n + 1);
            key.back() = parent->key[index];
            parent->key[index] = sibling->key.front();
            // shift all keys of right sibling left by 1
            std::shift_left(sibling->key.begin(), sibling->key.end(), 1);
            if (!leaf) {
                child[n] = std::move(sibling->child[0]);
                // shift all children of right sibling left by 1
                std::shift_left(sibling->child.begin(), sibling->child.end(), 1);
            }
            sibling->setN(sibling->getN() - 1);
            validateChild();
            sibling->validateChild();
        }

        void RightRotate() noexcept {
            assert(index - 1 < parent->child.size());
            auto sibling = parent->child[index - 1].get();
            // right rotation
            setN(n + 1);
            // shift all keys of node right by 1
            std::shift_right(key.begin(), key.end(), 1);
            key.front() = parent->key[index - 1];
            parent->key[index - 1] = sibling->key.back();
            if (!leaf) {
                // shift all children of node right by 1
                std::shift_right(child.begin(), child.end(), 1);
                child[0] = std::move(sibling->child[sibling->getN()]);
            }
            sibling->setN(sibling->getN() - 1);
            validateChild();
            sibling->validateChild();
        }
    };
    
    struct BTreeIterator {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        
        Node* node;
        std::vector<T>::iterator it;
        
        void Increment() {
            if (it == node->key.end()) {
                return;
            }
            if (node->leaf) {
                ++it;
                while (node->parent && it == node->key.end()) {
                    it = node->parent->key.begin() + node->index;
                    node = node->parent;
                }
            } else {
                auto i = std::distance(node->key.begin(), it);
                node = node->child[i + 1]->LeftmostLeaf();
                it = node->key.begin();
            }
        }
        
        void Decrement() {
            auto i = std::distance(node->key.begin(), it);
            if (!node->leaf) {
                node = node->child[i]->RightmostLeaf();
                it = node->key.begin() + node->key.size() - 1;
            } else {
                if (i > 0) {
                    --it;
                } else {
                    while (node->parent && node->index == 0) {
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                    if (node->index > 0) {
                        it = node->parent->key.begin() + node->index - 1;
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        BTreeIterator(Node* node, std::size_t i) : node {node} {
            assert(node && i <= node->key.size());
            it = node->key.begin() + i;
        }
        
        reference operator*() const {
            return *it;
        }
        
        pointer operator->() const {
            return it;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator& operator++() {
            Increment();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator operator++(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Increment();
            return temp;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator& operator--() {
            Decrement();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator operator--(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Decrement();
            return temp;
        }
        
        friend bool operator==(const BTreeIterator& x, const BTreeIterator& y) {
            return x.node == y.node && x.it == y.it;
        }
        
        friend bool operator!=(const BTreeIterator& x, const BTreeIterator& y) {
            return !(x == y);
        }
    };
    
    struct BTreeConstIterator {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = const T*;
        using reference = const T&;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        
        const Node* node;
        std::vector<T>::const_iterator it;
        
        void Increment() {
            if (it == node->key.cend()) {
                return;
            }
            if (node->leaf) {
                ++it;
                while (node->parent && it == node->key.cend()) {
                    it = node->parent->key.cbegin() + node->index;
                    node = node->parent;
                }
            } else {
                auto i = std::distance(node->key.cbegin(), it);
                node = node->child[i + 1]->LeftmostLeaf();
                it = node->key.cbegin();
            }
        }
        
        void Decrement() {
            auto i = std::distance(node->key.cbegin(), it);
            if (!node->leaf) {
                node = node->child[i]->RightmostLeaf();
                it = node->key.cbegin() + node->key.size() - 1;
            } else {
                if (i > 0) {
                    --it;
                } else {
                    while (node->parent && node->index == 0) {
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                    if (node->index > 0) {
                        it = node->parent->key.cbegin() + node->index - 1;
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        BTreeConstIterator(const Node* node, std::size_t i) : node {node} {
            assert(node && i <= node->key.size());
            it = node->key.cbegin() + i;
        }
        
        reference operator*() const {
            return *it;
        }
        
        pointer operator->() const {
            return it;
        }
        
        BTreeConstIterator& operator++() {
            Increment();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeConstIterator operator++(int) {
            BTreeConstIterator temp = *this;
            Increment();
            return temp;
        }
        
        BTreeConstIterator& operator--() {
            Decrement();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeConstIterator operator--(int) {
            BTreeConstIterator temp = *this;
            Decrement();
            return temp;
        }
        
        friend bool operator==(const BTreeConstIterator& x, const BTreeConstIterator& y) {
            return x.node == y.node && x.it == y.it;
        }
        
        friend bool operator!=(const BTreeConstIterator& x, const BTreeConstIterator& y) {
            return !(x == y);
        }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
    
    using iterator = BTreeIterator;
    using const_iterator = BTreeConstIterator;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
    
    std::pair<const Node*, std::size_t> Search(const Node* x, const T& k) const {
        std::size_t i = std::distance(x->key.begin(), std::ranges::lower_bound(x->key, k, Comp()));
        if (i < x->getN() && k == x->key[i]) { // equal? key found
            return {x, i};
        } else if (x->leaf) { // no child, key is not in the tree
            return {nullptr, 0};
        } else { // search on child between range
            return Search(x->child[i].get(), k);
        }
    }

    void InsertNonFull(Node* x, const T& k) {
        if (x->leaf) { // key should be inserted only at leaf
            InsertToLeaf(x, k);
        } else {
            auto i = std::distance(x->key.begin(), std::ranges::upper_bound(x->key, k, Comp()));
            if (x->child[i]->isFull()) { // is full? then split
                SplitChild(x, i);
                if (Comp()(x->key[i], k)) {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            InsertNonFull(x->child[i].get(), k); // recursively insert
        }
    }

    void InsertToLeaf(Node* node, const T& k) {
        assert(node->leaf);
        auto i = std::distance(node->key.begin(), std::ranges::upper_bound(node->key, k, Comp()));
        node->setN(node->getN() + 1);
        std::shift_right(node->key.begin() + i, node->key.end(), 1);
        node->key[i] = k;
        // n cannot exceeds 2t - 1, because in that case
        // its parent should've called SplitChild on x before
        assert(node->getN() < 2 * t);
    }

    // split x->child[i]
    void SplitChild(Node* x, std::size_t i) noexcept {
        if (!x) {
            return;
        }
        auto y = x->child[i].get();
        if (!y) {
            return;
        }
        // x cannot be full, because in that case its parent should've called SplitChild on x before
        assert(!x->isFull() && y->isFull());
        auto z = std::make_unique<Node>(); // will be y's right sibling
        z->leaf = y->leaf;
        z->setN(t - 1);
        // bring right half keys from y
        std::ranges::move(range_from(y->key, t), z->key.begin());
        if (!y->leaf) {
            // bring right half children from y
            std::ranges::move(range_from(y->child, t), z->child.begin());
            z->validateChild();
        }
        x->setN(x->getN() + 1);
        // shift children of x right by 1 from i + 1
        std::shift_right(x->child.begin() + i + 1, x->child.end(), 1);
        x->child[i + 1] = std::move(z);
        // shift keys of x right by 1 from i
        std::shift_right(x->key.begin() + i, x->key.end(), 1);
        x->key[i] = y->key[t - 1];
        y->setN(t - 1);
        x->validateChild();
        y->validateChild();
    }

    void Delete(Node* x, const T& k) noexcept {
        std::size_t i = std::distance(x->key.begin(), std::ranges::lower_bound(x->key, k, Comp()));
        if (i < x->getN() && k == x->key[i]) { // equal? key found
            Delete(x, k, i);
        } else if (x->leaf) { // no child, key is not in the tree
            return;
        } else { // search on child between range
            Node* next = x->child[i].get();
            if (x->child[i]->hasMinimalKeys()) {
                if (i + 1 < x->child.size() && x->child[i + 1]->canTakeKey()) {
                    x->child[i]->LeftRotate();
                } else if (i - 1 < x->child.size() && x->child[i - 1]->canTakeKey()) {
                    x->child[i]->RightRotate();
                } else if (i + 1 < x->child.size()) {
                    x->Merge(i);
                    next = x->child[i].get();
                    if (x == root.get() && x->isEmpty()) {
                        // shrink tree in height, merged child should be a new root
                        root = std::move(x->child[i]);
                        root->parent = nullptr;
                    }
                } else if (i - 1 < x->child.size()) {
                    x->Merge(i - 1);
                    next = x->child[i - 1].get();
                    if (x == root.get() && x->isEmpty()) {
                        // shrink tree in height, merged child should be a new root
                        root = std::move(x->child[i - 1]);
                        root->parent = nullptr;
                    }
                }
            }
            Delete(next, k);
        }
    }

    void Delete(Node* x, const T& k, std::size_t i) noexcept {
        assert(x->key[i] == k);
        if (x->leaf) {
            // directly erase from leaf
            DeleteToLeaf(x, i);
        } else if (x->child[i]->canTakeKey()) {
            // find predecessor and swap keys
            auto predLeaf = x->child[i]->RightmostLeaf();
            std::swap(predLeaf->key.back(), x->key[i]);
            // now k is in left child, search there
            Delete(x->child[i].get(), k);
        } else if (x->child[i + 1]->canTakeKey()) {
            // find successor and swap keys
            auto succLeaf = x->child[i + 1]->LeftmostLeaf();
            std::swap(succLeaf->key.front(), x->key[i]);
            // now k is in right child, search there
            Delete(x->child[i + 1].get(), k);
        } else {
            // merge two children
            x->Merge(i);
            Node* next = x->child[i].get();
            if (x == root.get() && x->getN() == 0) {
                // shrink tree in height, merged child should be a new root
                root = std::move(x->child[i]);
                root->parent = nullptr;
            }
            Delete(next, k);
        }
    }

    void DeleteToLeaf(Node* node, std::size_t i) {
        assert(node->leaf);
        std::shift_left(node->key.begin() + i, node->key.end(), 1);
        node->setN(node->getN() - 1);
        assert(node == root.get() || node->getN() >= t - 1);
    }
    
    void ValidateIterators() {
        begin_ = iterator(root->LeftmostLeaf(), 0);
        cbegin_ = const_iterator(root->LeftmostLeaf(), 0);
        end_ = iterator(root.get(), root->getN());
        cend_ = const_iterator(root.get(), root->getN());
    }
    
    iterator begin_;
    const_iterator cbegin_;
    iterator end_;
    const_iterator cend_;

public:
    BTree() : root {std::make_unique<Node>()},
        begin_ {root.get(), 0}, cbegin_ {root.get(), 0}, end_ {root.get(), 0}, cend_ {root.get(), 0} {
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::pair<const Node*, std::size_t> Search(const T& k) const {
        return Search(root.get(), k);
    }

    void Insert(const T& k) noexcept {
        if (root->isFull()) { // if root is full then make it as a child of new root - and split
            auto s = std::make_unique<Node>();
            s->leaf = false;
            s->setN(0);
            s->child[0] = std::move(root);
            root = std::move(s);
            SplitChild(root.get(), 0);
            InsertNonFull(root.get(), k);
        } else {
            InsertNonFull(root.get(), k);
        }
        ValidateIterators();
    }

    void Delete(const T& k) {
        Delete(root.get(), k);
        ValidateIterators();
    }
    
    iterator begin() {
        return begin_;
    }
    
    const_iterator begin() const {
        return cbegin_;
    }
    
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return cbegin_;
    }
    
    iterator end() {
        return end_;
    }
    
    const_iterator end() const {
        return cend_;
    }
    
    const_iterator cend() const {
        return cend_;
    }
    
    reverse_iterator rbegin() {
        return reverse_iterator(end_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cend_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cend_);
    }
    
    reverse_iterator rend() {
        return reverse_iterator(begin_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cbegin_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cbegin_);
    }
    

};

int main() {
    BTree<int, 2> tree;

    constexpr std::size_t N = 100;

    std::vector<int> v (N);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::ranges::shuffle(v, gen);

    for (auto n : v) {
        tree.Insert(n);
        for (const auto& key : tree) {
            std::cout << key << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    assert(std::ranges::all_of(v, [&tree](auto n){return tree.Search(n).first != nullptr;}));
   

    // should output 1 2 3 ... N
    for (const auto& key : tree) {
        std::cout << key << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::ranges::shuffle(v, gen);

    for (auto n : v) {
        tree.Delete(n);
        for (const auto& key : tree) {
            std::cout << key << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Don't restrict the type of key

You'll notice that ordered STL containers such as [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) put no constraints on the type of the key, neither using SFINAE, concepts nor a mention in the description. The reason is that you are allowed to specify your own compare function, which you can use to provide a way to order keys even if the keys themselves do not have a total order.

As an example: suppose I want to store two-dimensional coordinates in a B-tree, and order them based on their x coordinate. Two-dimensional coordinates themselves do not have a well-defined ordering, so your `concept Key` would prevent it from being usable with `BTree`, even though it is trivial to write a comparison function that just compares the x coordinate of two keys.

## Naming things

Avoid very short names for variables and types, unless it is a commonly used name. For example, `T` is fine for the template type of a key or value, `n` is a common abbreviation for a "number" of things. But `t` is a bad choice for the number of children of a node. I suggest you replace it with `fanout`.

I also recommend you use the plural for names of containers that can hold multiple elements. So `keys` instead of `key`, `children` instead of `child`.

Be consistent when naming things. I see both camelCase and PascalCase used for member functions.

## Add more `assert()`s where appropriate

You already use `assert()` in a few cases, but it can be done in a lot more places. For example, in `BTree::Node::setN`, you can add:

```
assert(N <= 2 * t - 1);
```

The iterator operators could also use some `assert()` statements to check that you don't try to iterate past the beginning or end of the tree, and so on.

## Optimize your iterators

There's a little bit of redundancy in your iterators:

```
Node* node;
std::vector<T>::iterator it;
```

Here, `it` also contains a pointer to `node->key`. It's better to just store the integer index into `node->key`. That way, you also don't have to jump through hoops to get an index into `node->child` as well:

```
Node *node;
size_t index;
```

## Optimize your `Node`s

You also store some redundant information in each `Node`. Consider that `key.size()` is equal to `n`, and `child.size()` is equal to `n + 1` for interior nodes, and `child.empty() == true` for leaf nodes. So `n` and `leaf` store redundant information. Removing those two variables gets rid of 16 bytes on 64-bit architectures, and there's less state that needs to be kept in sync.

In principle you could also remove `parent` and `index`. This makes the iterators and the rotation operations more complex though, so I would probably keep it as it is now.

Comment: One more thing, I noticed that the key is mutable by non-const iterator, ruining the invariants of tree. So I'm planning to make keys immutable and provide a way to store (key, value) pair as std::map does, and provide a way to customize allocator using std::pmr things, to reduce memory fragmentation. Thanks for great feedback!

Comment: Sounds like good ideas! Post a new question when you want your changes to be reviewed.