# C++20 B-Tree v1.0 with disk file supports and perf test

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20

I've improved my in-memory B-Tree ([Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248231/c-b-tree-in-c20-iterator-support)) to release a B-Tree with support for memory-mapped disk files and fixed-size allocators:

Repository: https://github.com/frozenca/BTree

Code:

```
#ifndef __FC_BTREE_H__
#define __FC_BTREE_H__

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace frozenca {

template <typename T>
concept Containable = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T>;

using index_t = std::ptrdiff_t;
using attr_t = std::int32_t;

template <typename T> struct TreePairRef { using type = T; };

template <typename T, typename U> struct TreePairRef<std::pair<T, U>> {
  using type = std::pair<const T &, U &>;
};

template <typename TreePair> using PairRefType = TreePairRef<TreePair>::type;

template <Containable K, typename V> struct Projection {
  const K &operator()(const V &value) const noexcept {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<K, V>) {
      return value;
    } else {
      return value.first;
    }
  }
};

template <Containable K, typename V, index_t Fanout, index_t FanoutLeaf,
          typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename Alloc>
requires(Fanout >= 2 && FanoutLeaf >= 2) class BTreeBase;

template <Containable K, typename V, index_t Fanout, index_t FanoutLeaf,
          typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename Alloc, typename T>
BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc> join(
    BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc> &&tree_left,
    T &&raw_value,
    BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc> &&
        tree_right) requires std::is_constructible_v<V, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

template <Containable K, typename V, index_t Fanout, index_t FanoutLeaf,
          typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename Alloc, typename T>
std::pair<BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>,
          BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>>
split(
    BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc> &&tree,
    T &&raw_value) requires std::is_constructible_v<V, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

template <Containable K, typename V, index_t Fanout, index_t FanoutLeaf,
          typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename Alloc>
requires(Fanout >= 2 && FanoutLeaf >= 2) class BTreeBase {
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Alloc::value_type, V>,
                "Allocator value type is not V");

  // invariant: V is either K or pair<const K, Value> for some Value type.
  static constexpr bool is_set_ = std::is_same_v<K, V>;

  static_assert(
      std::indirect_strict_weak_order<
          Comp, std::projected<std::ranges::iterator_t<std::vector<V, Alloc>>,
                               Projection<K, V>>>);

  struct Node {
    // invariant: except root, t - 1 <= #(key) <= 2 * t - 1
    // invariant: for root, 0 <= #(key) <= 2 * t - 1
    // invariant: keys are sorted
    // invariant: for internal nodes, t <= #(child) == (#(key) + 1)) <= 2 * t
    // invariant: for root, 0 <= #(child) == (#(key) + 1)) <= 2 * t
    // invariant: for leaves, 0 == #(child)
    // invariant: child_0 <= key_0 <= child_1 <= ... <=  key_(N - 1) <= child_N
    std::vector<V, Alloc> keys_ = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children_;
    Node *parent_ = nullptr;
    index_t size_ = 0;
    index_t index_ = 0;
    attr_t height_ = 0;

    // can throw bad_alloc
    explicit Node(const Alloc &alloc, bool is_leaf = true) : keys_(alloc) {
      keys_.reserve(2 * (is_leaf ? FanoutLeaf : Fanout) - 1);
    }

    Node(const Node &node) = delete;
    Node &operator=(const Node &node) = delete;
    Node(Node &&node) = delete;
    Node &operator=(Node &&node) = delete;

    void clone(const Node &other) {
      keys_ = other.keys_;
      size_ = other.size_;
      if (!other.is_leaf()) {
        assert(is_leaf());
        children_.reserve(other.fanout() * 2);
        children_.resize(other.children_.size());
        for (index_t i = 0; i < ssize(other.children_); ++i) {
          children_[i] =
              std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_, other.children_[i]->is_leaf());
          children_[i]->clone(other.children_[i]);
          children_[i]->parent_ = this;
          children_[i]->index_ = i;
          children_[i]->height_ = other.children_[i].height_;
        }
      }
    }

    [[nodiscard]] index_t fanout() const noexcept {
      if (is_leaf()) {
        return FanoutLeaf;
      } else {
        return Fanout;
      }
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool is_leaf() const noexcept { return children_.empty(); }

    [[nodiscard]] bool is_full() const noexcept {
      return ssize(keys_) == 2 * fanout() - 1;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool can_take_key() const noexcept {
      return ssize(keys_) > fanout() - 1;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] bool has_minimal_keys() const noexcept {
      return parent_ && ssize(keys_) == fanout() - 1;
    }
  };

  struct BTreeNonConstIterTraits {
    using difference_type = index_t;
    using value_type = V;
    using pointer = V *;
    using reference = V &;
    using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_concept = iterator_category;

    static reference make_ref(value_type &val) noexcept { return val; }
  };

  struct BTreeConstIterTraits {
    using difference_type = index_t;
    using value_type = V;
    using pointer = const V *;
    using reference = const V &;
    using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_concept = iterator_category;

    static reference make_ref(const value_type &val) noexcept { return val; }
  };

  struct BTreeRefIterTraits {
    using difference_type = index_t;
    using value_type = V;
    using pointer = V *;
    using reference = PairRefType<V>;
    using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_concept = iterator_category;

    static reference make_ref(value_type &val) noexcept {
      return {std::cref(val.first), std::ref(val.second)};
    }
  };

  template <typename IterTraits> struct BTreeIterator {
    using difference_type = IterTraits::difference_type;
    using value_type = IterTraits::value_type;
    using pointer = IterTraits::pointer;
    using reference = IterTraits::reference;
    using iterator_category = IterTraits::iterator_category;
    using iterator_concept = IterTraits::iterator_concept;

    Node *node_ = nullptr;
    index_t index_;

    BTreeIterator() noexcept = default;

    BTreeIterator(Node *node, index_t i) noexcept : node_{node}, index_{i} {
      assert(node_ && i >= 0 && i <= std::ssize(node_->keys_));
    }

    template <typename IterTraitsOther>
    BTreeIterator(const BTreeIterator<IterTraitsOther> &other) noexcept
        : BTreeIterator(other.node_, other.index_) {}

    reference operator*() const noexcept {
      return IterTraits::make_ref(node_->keys_[index_]);
    }

    pointer operator->() const noexcept { return &(node_->keys_[index_]); }

    // useful remark:
    // incrementing/decrementing iterator in an internal node will always
    // produce an iterator in a leaf node,
    // incrementing/decrementing iterator in a leaf node will always produce
    // an iterator in a leaf node for non-boundary keys,
    // an iterator in an internal node for boundary keys

    void climb() noexcept {
      while (node_->parent_ && index_ == std::ssize(node_->keys_)) {
        index_ = node_->index_;
        node_ = node_->parent_;
      }
    }

    void increment() noexcept {
      // we don't do past to end() check for efficiency
      if (!node_->is_leaf()) {
        node_ = leftmost_leaf(node_->children_[index_ + 1].get());
        index_ = 0;
      } else {
        ++index_;
        while (node_->parent_ && index_ == std::ssize(node_->keys_)) {
          index_ = node_->index_;
          node_ = node_->parent_;
        }
      }
    }

    void decrement() noexcept {
      if (!node_->is_leaf()) {
        node_ = rightmost_leaf(node_->children_[index_].get());
        index_ = std::ssize(node_->keys_) - 1;
      } else if (index_ > 0) {
        --index_;
      } else {
        while (node_->parent_ && node_->index_ == 0) {
          node_ = node_->parent_;
        }
        if (node_->index_ > 0) {
          index_ = node_->index_ - 1;
          node_ = node_->parent_;
        }
      }
    }

    bool verify() noexcept {
      return !node_->parent_ || (index_ < std::ssize(node_->keys_));
    }

    BTreeIterator &operator++() noexcept {
      increment();
      assert(verify());
      return *this;
    }

    BTreeIterator operator++(int) noexcept {
      BTreeIterator temp = *this;
      increment();
      assert(verify());
      return temp;
    }

    BTreeIterator &operator--() noexcept {
      decrement();
      assert(verify());
      return *this;
    }

    BTreeIterator operator--(int) noexcept {
      BTreeIterator temp = *this;
      decrement();
      assert(verify());
      return temp;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const BTreeIterator &x,
                           const BTreeIterator &y) noexcept {
      return x.node_ == y.node_ && x.index_ == y.index_;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const BTreeIterator &x,
                           const BTreeIterator &y) noexcept {
      return !(x == y);
    }
  };

public:
  using key_type = K;
  using value_type = V;
  using reference_type = std::conditional_t<is_set_, const V &, PairRefType<V>>;
  using const_reference_type = const V &;
  using node_type = Node;
  using size_type = std::size_t;
  using difference_type = index_t;
  using allocator_type = Alloc;
  using Proj = Projection<K, V>;

  // invariant: K cannot be mutated
  // so if V is K, uses a const iterator.
  // if V is pair<K, V>, uses a non-const iterator (but only value can
  // be mutated)

  // invariant: K cannot be mutated
  // so if V is K, uses a const iterator.
  // if V is pair<K, V>, uses a non-const iterator (but only value can
  // be mutated)
  using nonconst_iterator_type = BTreeIterator<BTreeNonConstIterTraits>;
  using iterator_type = BTreeIterator<
      std::conditional_t<is_set_, BTreeConstIterTraits, BTreeRefIterTraits>>;
  using const_iterator_type = BTreeIterator<BTreeConstIterTraits>;
  using reverse_iterator_type = std::reverse_iterator<iterator_type>;
  using const_reverse_iterator_type =
      std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator_type>;

private:
  Alloc alloc_;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> root_;
  iterator_type begin_;

public:
  BTreeBase(const Alloc &alloc = Alloc{})
      : alloc_{alloc}, root_{std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_)}, begin_{
                                                                  root_.get(),
                                                                  0} {}

  BTreeBase(std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
            const Alloc &alloc = Alloc{})
      : BTreeBase(alloc) {
    for (auto val : init) {
      insert(std::move(val));
    }
  }

  BTreeBase(const BTreeBase &other) {
    alloc_ = other.alloc_;
    if (other.root_) {
      root_ = std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_, other.root_.is_leaf());
      root_->clone(*(other.root_));
      root_->parent_ = nullptr;
    }
    begin_ = iterator_type(leftmost_leaf(root_.get()), 0);
  }
  BTreeBase &operator=(const BTreeBase &other) {
    BTreeBase tree(other);
    this->swap(tree);
    return *this;
  }
  BTreeBase(BTreeBase &&other) noexcept = default;
  BTreeBase &operator=(BTreeBase &&other) noexcept = default;

  void swap(BTreeBase &other) noexcept {
    std::swap(alloc_, other.alloc_);
    std::swap(root_, other.root_);
    std::swap(begin_, other.begin_);
  }

  bool verify(const Node *node) const {
    // invariant: node never null
    assert(node);

    // invariant: except root, t - 1 <= #(key) <= 2 * t - 1
    assert(!node->parent_ ||
           (std::ssize(node->keys_) >= node->fanout() - 1 &&
            std::ssize(node->keys_) <= 2 * node->fanout() - 1));

    // invariant: keys are sorted
    assert(std::ranges::is_sorted(node->keys_, Comp{}, Proj{}));

    // invariant: for internal nodes, t <= #(child) == (#(key) + 1)) <= 2 * t
    assert(!node->parent_ || node->is_leaf() ||
           (std::ssize(node->children_) >= node->fanout() &&
            std::ssize(node->children_) == ssize(node->keys_) + 1 &&
            std::ssize(node->children_) <= 2 * node->fanout()));

    // index check
    assert(!node->parent_ ||
           node == node->parent_->children_[node->index_].get());

    // invariant: child_0 <= key_0 <= child_1 <= ... <=  key_(N - 1) <=
    // child_N
    if (!node->is_leaf()) {
      auto num_keys = std::ssize(node->keys_);

      for (index_t i = 0; i < std::ssize(node->keys_); ++i) {
        assert(node->children_[i]);
        assert(!Comp{}(Proj{}(node->keys_[i]),
                       Proj{}(node->children_[i]->keys_.back())));
        assert(!Comp{}(Proj{}(node->children_[i + 1]->keys_.front()),
                       Proj{}(node->keys_[i])));
        // parent check
        assert(node->children_[i]->parent_ == node);
        // recursive check
        assert(verify(node->children_[i].get()));
        assert(node->height_ == node->children_[i]->height_ + 1);
        num_keys += node->children_[i]->size_;
      }
      assert(verify(node->children_.back().get()));
      assert(node->height_ == node->children_.back()->height_ + 1);
      num_keys += node->children_.back()->size_;
      assert(node->size_ == num_keys);
    } else {
      assert(node->size_ == std::ssize(node->keys_));
      assert(node->height_ == 0);
    }

    return true;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] bool verify() const {
    assert(begin_ == iterator_type(leftmost_leaf(root_.get()), 0));
    assert(verify(root_.get()));
    return true;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] iterator_type begin() noexcept { return begin_; }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type begin() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(begin_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type cbegin() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(begin_);
  }

  [[nodiscard]] iterator_type end() noexcept {
    return iterator_type(root_.get(), std::ssize(root_->keys_));
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type end() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(root_.get(), std::ssize(root_->keys_));
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_iterator_type cend() const noexcept {
    return const_iterator_type(root_.get(), std::ssize(root_->keys_));
  }

  [[nodiscard]] reverse_iterator_type rbegin() noexcept {
    return reverse_iterator_type(begin());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type rbegin() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(begin());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type crbegin() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(cbegin());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] reverse_iterator_type rend() noexcept {
    return reverse_iterator_type(end());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type rend() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(end());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] const_reverse_iterator_type crend() const noexcept {
    return const_reverse_iterator_type(cend());
  }

  [[nodiscard]] bool empty() const noexcept { return root_->size_ == 0; }

  [[nodiscard]] size_type size() const noexcept {
    return static_cast<size_type>(root_->size_);
  }

  void clear() {
    root_ = std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_);
    begin_ = iterator_type(root_.get(), 0);
  }

protected:
  static Node *rightmost_leaf(Node *curr) noexcept {
    while (curr && !curr->is_leaf()) {
      curr = curr->children_[std::ssize(curr->children_) - 1].get();
    }
    return curr;
  }

  static const Node *rightmost_leaf(const Node *curr) noexcept {
    while (curr && !curr->is_leaf()) {
      curr = curr->children_[std::ssize(curr->children_) - 1].get();
    }
    return curr;
  }

  static Node *leftmost_leaf(Node *curr) noexcept {
    while (curr && !curr->is_leaf()) {
      curr = curr->children_[0].get();
    }
    return curr;
  }

  static const Node *leftmost_leaf(const Node *curr) noexcept {
    while (curr && !curr->is_leaf()) {
      curr = curr->children_[0].get();
    }
    return curr;
  }

  void promote_root_if_necessary() {
    if (root_->keys_.empty()) {
      assert(std::ssize(root_->children_) == 1);
      root_ = std::move(root_->children_[0]);
      root_->index_ = 0;
      root_->parent_ = nullptr;
    }
  }

  void set_begin() { begin_ = iterator_type(leftmost_leaf(root_.get()), 0); }

  // node brings a key from parent
  // parent brings a key from right sibling
  // node brings a child from right sibling
  void left_rotate(Node *node) {
    auto parent = node->parent_;
    assert(node && parent && parent->children_[node->index_].get() == node &&
           node->index_ + 1 < std::ssize(parent->children_) &&
           parent->children_[node->index_ + 1]->can_take_key());
    auto sibling = parent->children_[node->index_ + 1].get();

    node->keys_.push_back(std::move(parent->keys_[node->index_]));
    parent->keys_[node->index_] = std::move(sibling->keys_.front());
    std::shift_left(sibling->keys_.begin(), sibling->keys_.end(), 1);
    sibling->keys_.pop_back();

    node->size_++;
    sibling->size_--;

    if (!node->is_leaf()) {
      const auto orphan_size = sibling->children_.front()->size_;
      node->size_ += orphan_size;
      sibling->size_ -= orphan_size;

      sibling->children_.front()->parent_ = node;
      sibling->children_.front()->index_ = std::ssize(node->children_);
      node->children_.push_back(std::move(sibling->children_.front()));
      std::shift_left(sibling->children_.begin(), sibling->children_.end(), 1);
      sibling->children_.pop_back();
      for (auto &&child : sibling->children_) {
        child->index_--;
      }
    }
  }

  // left_rotate() * n
  void left_rotate_n(Node *node, index_t n) {
    assert(n >= 1);
    if (n == 1) {
      left_rotate(node);
      return;
    }

    auto parent = node->parent_;
    assert(node && parent && parent->children_[node->index_].get() == node &&
           node->index_ + 1 < std::ssize(parent->children_));
    auto sibling = parent->children_[node->index_ + 1].get();
    assert(std::ssize(sibling->keys_) >= (node->fanout() - 1) + n);

    // brings one key from parent
    node->keys_.push_back(std::move(parent->keys_[node->index_]));
    // brings n - 1 keys from sibling
    std::ranges::move(sibling->keys_ | std::views::take(n - 1),
                      std::back_inserter(node->keys_));
    // parent brings one key from sibling
    parent->keys_[node->index_] = std::move(sibling->keys_[n - 1]);
    std::shift_left(sibling->keys_.begin(), sibling->keys_.end(), n);
    sibling->keys_.resize(std::ssize(sibling->keys_) - n);

    node->size_ += n;
    sibling->size_ -= n;

    if (!node->is_leaf()) {
      // brings n children from sibling
      index_t orphan_size = 0;
      index_t immigrant_index = std::ssize(node->children_);
      for (auto &&immigrant : sibling->children_ | std::views::take(n)) {
        immigrant->parent_ = node;
        immigrant->index_ = immigrant_index++;
        orphan_size += immigrant->size_;
      }
      node->size_ += orphan_size;
      sibling->size_ -= orphan_size;

      std::ranges::move(sibling->children_ | std::views::take(n),
                        std::back_inserter(node->children_));
      std::shift_left(sibling->children_.begin(), sibling->children_.end(), n);
      sibling->keys_.resize(std::ssize(sibling->keys_) - n);
      index_t sibling_index = 0;
      for (auto &&child : sibling->children_) {
        child->index_ = sibling_index++;
      }
    }
  }

  // node brings a key from parent
  // parent brings a key from left sibling
  // node brings a child from left sibling
  void right_rotate(Node *node) {
    auto parent = node->parent_;
    assert(node && parent && parent->children_[node->index_].get() == node &&
           node->index_ - 1 >= 0 &&
           parent->children_[node->index_ - 1]->can_take_key());
    auto sibling = parent->children_[node->index_ - 1].get();

    node->keys_.insert(node->keys_.begin(),
                       std::move(parent->keys_[node->index_ - 1]));
    parent->keys_[node->index_ - 1] = std::move(sibling->keys_.back());
    sibling->keys_.pop_back();

    node->size_++;
    sibling->size_--;

    if (!node->is_leaf()) {
      const auto orphan_size = sibling->children_.back()->size_;
      node->size_ += orphan_size;
      sibling->size_ -= orphan_size;

      sibling->children_.back()->parent_ = node;
      sibling->children_.back()->index_ = 0;

      node->children_.insert(node->children_.begin(),
                             std::move(sibling->children_.back()));
      sibling->children_.pop_back();
      for (auto &&child : node->children_ | std::views::drop(1)) {
        child->index_++;
      }
    }
  }

  // right_rotate() * n
  void right_rotate_n(Node *node, index_t n) {
    assert(n >= 1);
    if (n == 1) {
      right_rotate(node);
      return;
    }

    auto parent = node->parent_;
    assert(node && parent && parent->children_[node->index_].get() == node &&
           node->index_ - 1 >= 0);
    auto sibling = parent->children_[node->index_ - 1].get();
    assert(std::ssize(sibling->keys_) >= (node->fanout() - 1) + n);

    // brings n - 1 keys from sibling
    std::ranges::move(sibling->keys_ |
                          std::views::drop(ssize(sibling->keys_) - n) |
                          std::views::take(n - 1),
                      std::back_inserter(node->keys_));
    // brings one key from parent
    node->keys_.push_back(std::move(parent->keys_[node->index_ - 1]));
    // parent brings one key from sibling
    parent->keys_[node->index_ - 1] = std::move(sibling->keys_.back());
    // right rotate n
    std::ranges::rotate(node->keys_ | std::views::reverse,
                        node->keys_.rbegin() + n);

    sibling->keys_.resize(std::ssize(sibling->keys_) - n);

    node->size_ += n;
    sibling->size_ -= n;

    if (!node->is_leaf()) {
      // brings n children from sibling
      index_t orphan_size = 0;
      index_t immigrant_index = 0;
      for (auto &&immigrant :
           sibling->children_ |
               std::views::drop(std::ssize(sibling->children_) - n)) {
        immigrant->parent_ = node;
        immigrant->index_ = immigrant_index++;
        orphan_size += immigrant->size_;
      }
      node->size_ += orphan_size;
      sibling->size_ -= orphan_size;

      std::ranges::move(
          sibling->children_ |
              std::views::drop(std::ssize(sibling->children_) - n),
          std::back_inserter(node->children_));
      std::ranges::rotate(node->children_ | std::views::reverse,
                          node->children_.rbegin() + n);
      sibling->children_.resize(std::ssize(sibling->children_) - n);
      index_t child_index = n;
      for (auto &&child : node->children_ | std::views::drop(n)) {
        child->index_ = child_index++;
      }
    }
  }

  const_iterator_type search(const K &key) const {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (x) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::lower_bound(x->keys_, key, Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (i < std::ssize(x->keys_) &&
          Proj{}(key) == Proj{}(x->keys_[i])) { // equal? key found
        return const_iterator_type(x, i);
      } else if (x->is_leaf()) { // no child, key is not in the tree
        return cend();
      } else { // search on child between range
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
    return cend();
  }

  nonconst_iterator_type find_lower_bound(const K &key) {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (x) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::lower_bound(x->keys_, key, Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (x->is_leaf()) {
        auto it = nonconst_iterator_type(x, i);
        it.climb();
        return it;
      } else {
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
    return nonconst_iterator_type(end());
  }

  const_iterator_type find_lower_bound(const K &key) const {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (x) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::lower_bound(x->keys_, key, Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (x->is_leaf()) {
        auto it = const_iterator_type(x, i);
        it.climb();
        return it;
      } else {
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
    return cend();
  }

  nonconst_iterator_type find_upper_bound(const K &key) {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (x) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::upper_bound(x->keys_, key, Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (x->is_leaf()) {
        auto it = nonconst_iterator_type(x, i);
        it.climb();
        return it;
      } else {
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
    return nonconst_iterator_type(end());
  }

  const_iterator_type find_upper_bound(const K &key) const {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (x) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::upper_bound(x->keys_, key, Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (x->is_leaf()) {
        auto it = const_iterator_type(x, i);
        it.climb();
        return it;
      } else {
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
    return cend();
  }

  // split child[i] to child[i], child[i + 1]
  void split_child(Node *y) {
    assert(y);
    auto i = y->index_;
    Node *x = y->parent_;
    assert(x && y == x->children_[i].get() && y->is_full() && !x->is_full());

    // split y's 2 * t keys
    // y will have left t - 1 keys
    // y->keys_[t - 1] will be a key of y->parent_
    // right t keys of y will be taken by y's right sibling

    auto z = std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_,
                                    y->is_leaf()); // will be y's right sibling
    z->parent_ = x;
    z->index_ = i + 1;
    z->height_ = y->height_;

    auto fanout = y->fanout();

    // bring right t keys from y
    std::ranges::move(y->keys_ | std::views::drop(fanout),
                      std::back_inserter(z->keys_));
    auto z_size = std::ssize(z->keys_);
    if (!y->is_leaf()) {
      z->children_.reserve(2 * fanout);
      // bring right half children from y
      std::ranges::move(y->children_ | std::views::drop(fanout),
                        std::back_inserter(z->children_));
      for (auto &&child : z->children_) {
        child->parent_ = z.get();
        child->index_ -= fanout;
        z_size += child->size_;
      }
      y->children_.resize(fanout);
    }
    z->size_ = z_size;
    y->size_ -= (z_size + 1);

    x->children_.insert(x->children_.begin() + i + 1, std::move(z));
    for (auto &&child : x->children_ | std::views::drop(i + 2)) {
      child->index_++;
    }

    x->keys_.insert(x->keys_.begin() + i, std::move(y->keys_[fanout - 1]));
    y->keys_.resize(fanout - 1);
  }

  // merge child[i + 1] and key[i] into child[i]
  void merge_child(Node *y) {
    assert(y);
    auto i = y->index_;
    Node *x = y->parent_;
    assert(x && y == x->children_[i].get() && !x->is_leaf() && i >= 0 &&
           i + 1 < ssize(x->children_));
    auto sibling = x->children_[i + 1].get();
    assert(std::ssize(y->keys_) + std::ssize(sibling->keys_) <=
           2 * y->fanout() - 2);

    auto immigrated_size = std::ssize(sibling->keys_);

    y->keys_.push_back(std::move(x->keys_[i]));
    // bring keys of child[i + 1]
    std::ranges::move(sibling->keys_, std::back_inserter(y->keys_));

    // bring children of child[i + 1]
    if (!y->is_leaf()) {
      index_t immigrant_index = std::ssize(y->children_);
      for (auto &&child : sibling->children_) {
        child->parent_ = y;
        child->index_ = immigrant_index++;
        immigrated_size += child->size_;
      }
      std::ranges::move(sibling->children_, std::back_inserter(y->children_));
    }
    y->size_ += immigrated_size + 1;

    // shift children from i + 1 left by 1 (because child[i + 1] is merged)
    std::shift_left(x->children_.begin() + i + 1, x->children_.end(), 1);
    // shift keys from i left by 1 (because key[i] is merged)
    std::shift_left(x->keys_.begin() + i, x->keys_.end(), 1);
    x->children_.pop_back();
    x->keys_.pop_back();

    for (auto &&child : x->children_ | std::views::drop(i + 1)) {
      child->index_--;
    }
  }

  // only used in join() when join() is called by split()
  // preinvariant: x is the leftmost of the root (left side)
  // or the rightmost (right side)

  // (left side) merge child[0], child[1] if necessary, and propagate to
  // possibly the root for right side it's child[n - 2], child[n - 1]
  void try_merge(Node *x, bool left_side) {
    assert(x && !x->is_leaf());
    if (std::ssize(x->children_) < 2) {
      return;
    }
    if (left_side) {
      auto first = x->children_[0].get();
      auto second = x->children_[1].get();
      auto fanout = first->fanout();

      if (std::ssize(first->keys_) + std::ssize(second->keys_) <=
          2 * fanout - 2) {
        // just merge to one node
        merge_child(first);
      } else if (std::ssize(first->keys_) < fanout - 1) {
        // first borrows key from second
        auto deficit = (fanout - 1 - std::ssize(first->keys_));

        // this is mathematically true, otherwise
        // #(first.keys) + #(second.keys) < 2 * t - 2, so it should be merged
        // before
        assert(std::ssize(second->keys_) > deficit + (fanout - 1));
        left_rotate_n(first, deficit);
      }
    } else {
      auto rfirst = x->children_.back().get();
      auto rsecond = x->children_[std::ssize(x->children_) - 2].get();
      auto fanout = rfirst->fanout();

      if (std::ssize(rfirst->keys_) + std::ssize(rsecond->keys_) <=
          2 * fanout - 2) {
        // just merge to one node
        merge_child(rsecond);
      } else if (std::ssize(rfirst->keys_) < fanout - 1) {
        // rfirst borrows key from rsecond
        auto deficit = (fanout - 1 - std::ssize(rfirst->keys_));

        assert(std::ssize(rsecond->keys_) > deficit + (fanout - 1));
        right_rotate_n(rfirst, deficit);
      }
    }
  }

  template <typename T>
  iterator_type
  insert_leaf(Node *node, index_t i,
              T &&value) requires std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, V> {
    assert(node && node->is_leaf() && !node->is_full());
    bool update_begin = (empty() || Comp{}(Proj{}(value), Proj{}(*begin_)));

    node->keys_.insert(node->keys_.begin() + i, std::forward<T>(value));
    iterator_type iter(node, i);
    if (update_begin) {
      assert(node == leftmost_leaf(root_.get()) && i == 0);
      begin_ = iter;
    }

    auto curr = node;
    while (curr) {
      curr->size_++;
      curr = curr->parent_;
    }

    assert(verify());
    return iter;
  }

  template <typename T>
  iterator_type insert_ub(T &&key) requires(
      AllowDup &&std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, V>) {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (true) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::upper_bound(x->keys_, Proj{}(key), Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (x->is_leaf()) {
        return insert_leaf(x, i, std::forward<T>(key));
      } else {
        if (x->children_[i]->is_full()) {
          split_child(x->children_[i].get());
          if (Comp{}(Proj{}(x->keys_[i]), Proj{}(key))) {
            ++i;
          }
        }
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
  }

  template <typename T>
  std::pair<iterator_type, bool>
  insert_lb(T &&key) requires(!AllowDup &&
                              std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, V>) {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (true) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::lower_bound(x->keys_, Proj{}(key), Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (i < std::ssize(x->keys_) && Proj{}(key) == Proj{}(x->keys_[i])) {
        return {iterator_type(x, i), false};
      } else if (x->is_leaf()) {
        return {insert_leaf(x, i, std::forward<T>(key)), true};
      } else {
        if (x->children_[i]->is_full()) {
          split_child(x->children_[i].get());
          if (Comp{}(Proj{}(x->keys_[i]), Proj{}(key))) {
            ++i;
          }
        }
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
  }

  iterator_type erase_leaf(Node *node, index_t i) {
    assert(node && i >= 0 && i < std::ssize(node->keys_) && node->is_leaf() &&
           !node->has_minimal_keys());
    bool update_begin = (begin_ == iterator_type(node, i));
    std::shift_left(node->keys_.begin() + i, node->keys_.end(), 1);
    node->keys_.pop_back();
    iterator_type iter(node, i);
    iter.climb();
    if (update_begin) {
      begin_ = iter;
    }
    auto curr = node;
    while (curr) {
      curr->size_--;
      curr = curr->parent_;
    }
    assert(verify());
    return iter;
  }

  size_t erase_lb(Node *x, const K &key) requires(!AllowDup) {
    while (true) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::lower_bound(x->keys_, key, Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (i < ssize(x->keys_) && key == Proj{}(x->keys_[i])) {
        // key found
        assert(x->is_leaf() || i + 1 < std::ssize(x->children_));
        if (x->is_leaf()) {
          erase_leaf(x, i);
          return 1;
        } else if (x->children_[i]->can_take_key()) {
          // swap key with pred
          nonconst_iterator_type iter(x, i);
          auto pred = std::prev(iter);
          assert(pred.node_ == rightmost_leaf(x->children_[i].get()));
          std::iter_swap(pred, iter);
          // search pred
          x = x->children_[i].get();
        } else if (x->children_[i + 1]->can_take_key()) {
          // swap key with succ
          nonconst_iterator_type iter(x, i);
          auto succ = std::next(iter);
          assert(succ.node_ == leftmost_leaf(x->children_[i + 1].get()));
          std::iter_swap(succ, iter);
          // search succ
          x = x->children_[i + 1].get();
        } else {
          auto next = x->children_[i].get();
          merge_child(next);
          promote_root_if_necessary();
          x = next;
        }
      } else if (x->is_leaf()) {
        // no child, key is not in the tree
        return 0;
      } else {
        auto next = x->children_[i].get();
        if (x->children_[i]->has_minimal_keys()) {
          if (i + 1 < std::ssize(x->children_) &&
              x->children_[i + 1]->can_take_key()) {
            left_rotate(next);
          } else if (i - 1 >= 0 && x->children_[i - 1]->can_take_key()) {
            right_rotate(next);
          } else if (i + 1 < std::ssize(x->children_)) {
            merge_child(next);
            promote_root_if_necessary();
          } else if (i - 1 >= 0) {
            next = x->children_[i - 1].get();
            merge_child(next);
            promote_root_if_necessary();
          }
        }
        x = next;
      }
    }
  }

  iterator_type erase_hint(const V &value, std::vector<index_t> &hints) {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (true) {
      auto i = hints.back();
      hints.pop_back();
      if (hints.empty()) {
        // key found
        assert(i < std::ssize(x->keys_) && value == x->keys_[i]);
        assert(x->is_leaf() || i + 1 < std::ssize(x->children_));
        if (x->is_leaf()) {
          return erase_leaf(x, i);
        } else if (x->children_[i]->can_take_key()) {
          // swap key with pred
          nonconst_iterator_type iter(x, i);
          auto pred = std::prev(iter);
          assert(pred.node_ == rightmost_leaf(x->children_[i].get()));
          std::iter_swap(pred, iter);
          // search pred
          x = x->children_[i].get();
          auto curr = x;
          assert(curr->index_ == i);
          while (!curr->is_leaf()) {
            hints.push_back(std::ssize(curr->children_) - 1);
            curr = curr->children_.back().get();
          }
          hints.push_back(std::ssize(curr->keys_) - 1);
          std::ranges::reverse(hints);
        } else if (x->children_[i + 1]->can_take_key()) {
          // swap key with succ
          nonconst_iterator_type iter(x, i);
          auto succ = std::next(iter);
          assert(succ.node_ == leftmost_leaf(x->children_[i + 1].get()));
          std::iter_swap(succ, iter);
          // search succ
          x = x->children_[i + 1].get();
          auto curr = x;
          assert(curr->index_ == i + 1);
          while (!curr->is_leaf()) {
            hints.push_back(0);
            curr = curr->children_.front().get();
          }
          hints.push_back(0);
        } else {
          auto next = x->children_[i].get();
          merge_child(next);
          promote_root_if_necessary();
          x = next;
          // i'th key of x is now t - 1'th key of x->children_[i]
          hints.push_back(x->fanout() - 1);
        }
      } else {
        assert(!hints.empty());
        auto next = x->children_[i].get();
        if (x->children_[i]->has_minimal_keys()) {
          if (i + 1 < std::ssize(x->children_) &&
              x->children_[i + 1]->can_take_key()) {
            left_rotate(x->children_[i].get());
          } else if (i - 1 >= 0 && x->children_[i - 1]->can_take_key()) {
            right_rotate(x->children_[i].get());
            // x->children_[i] stuffs are shifted right by 1
            hints.back() += 1;
          } else if (i + 1 < std::ssize(x->children_)) {
            merge_child(next);
            promote_root_if_necessary();
          } else if (i - 1 >= 0) {
            next = x->children_[i - 1].get();
            merge_child(next);
            promote_root_if_necessary();
            // x->children_[i] stuffs are shifted right by t
            hints.back() += next->fanout();
          }
        }
        x = next;
      }
    }
  }

  size_type erase_range(iterator_type first, iterator_type last) {
    if (first == begin_ && last == end()) {
      auto cnt = size();
      clear();
      return cnt;
    }
    auto cnt = std::distance(first, last);
    for (auto i = cnt; i >= 0; --i) {
      first = erase(first);
    }
    return cnt;
  }

  V get_kth(index_t idx) const {
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (x) {
      if (x->is_leaf()) {
        assert(idx >= 0 && idx < std::ssize(x->keys_));
        return x->keys_[idx];
      } else {
        assert(!x->children_.empty());
        index_t i = 0;
        const auto n = std::ssize(x->keys_);
        Node *next = nullptr;
        for (; i < n; ++i) {
          auto child_sz = x->children_[i]->size_;
          if (idx < child_sz) {
            next = x->children_[i].get();
            break;
          } else if (idx == child_sz) {
            return x->keys_[i];
          } else {
            idx -= child_sz + 1;
          }
        }
        if (i == n) {
          next = x->children_[n].get();
        }
        x = next;
      }
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("unreachable");
  }

  index_t get_order(const_iterator_type iter) const {
    auto [node, idx] = iter;
    index_t order = 0;
    assert(node);
    if (!node->is_leaf()) {
      for (index_t i = 0; i <= idx; ++i) {
        order += node->children_[i]->size_;
      }
    }
    order += idx;
    while (node->parent_) {
      for (index_t i = 0; i < node->index_; ++i) {
        order += node->parent_->children_[i]->size_;
      }
      order += node->index_;
      node = node->parent_;
    }
    return order;
  }

public:
  iterator_type find(const K &key) { return iterator_type(search(key)); }

  const_iterator_type find(const K &key) const { return search(key); }

  bool contains(const K &key) const { return search(key) != cend(); }

  iterator_type lower_bound(const K &key) {
    return iterator_type(find_lower_bound(key));
  }

  const_iterator_type lower_bound(const K &key) const {
    return const_iterator_type(find_lower_bound(key));
  }

  iterator_type upper_bound(const K &key) {
    return iterator_type(find_upper_bound(key));
  }

  const_iterator_type upper_bound(const K &key) const {
    return const_iterator_type(find_upper_bound(key));
  }

  std::ranges::subrange<iterator_type> equal_range(const K &key) {
    return {iterator_type(find_lower_bound(key)),
            iterator_type(find_upper_bound(key))};
  }

  std::ranges::subrange<const_iterator_type> equal_range(const K &key) const {
    return {const_iterator_type(find_lower_bound(key)),
            const_iterator_type(find_upper_bound(key))};
  }

  std::ranges::subrange<const_iterator_type> enumerate(const K &a,
                                                       const K &b) const {
    if (Comp{}(b, a)) {
      throw std::invalid_argument("b < a in enumerate()");
    }
    return {const_iterator_type(find_lower_bound(a)),
            const_iterator_type(find_upper_bound(b))};
  }

  V kth(index_t idx) const {
    if (idx >= root_->size_) {
      throw std::invalid_argument("in kth() k >= size()");
    }
    return get_kth(idx);
  }

  index_t order(const_iterator_type iter) const {
    if (iter == cend()) {
      throw std::invalid_argument("attempt to get order in end()");
    }
    return get_order(iter);
  }

protected:
  template <typename T>
  std::conditional_t<AllowDup, iterator_type, std::pair<iterator_type, bool>>
  insert_value(T &&key) requires(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, V>) {
    if (root_->is_full()) {
      // if root is full then make it as a child of the new root
      auto new_root = std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_, false);
      root_->parent_ = new_root.get();
      new_root->size_ = root_->size_;
      new_root->height_ = root_->height_ + 1;
      new_root->children_.reserve(new_root->fanout() * 2);
      new_root->children_.push_back(std::move(root_));
      root_ = std::move(new_root);
      // and split
      split_child(root_->children_[0].get());
    }
    if constexpr (AllowDup) {
      return insert_ub(std::forward<T>(key));
    } else {
      return insert_lb(std::forward<T>(key));
    }
  }

public:
  std::conditional_t<AllowDup, iterator_type, std::pair<iterator_type, bool>>
  insert(const V &key) {
    return insert_value(key);
  }

  std::conditional_t<AllowDup, iterator_type, std::pair<iterator_type, bool>>
  insert(V &&key) {
    return insert_value(std::move(key));
  }

  template <typename... Args>
  std::conditional_t<AllowDup, iterator_type, std::pair<iterator_type, bool>>
  emplace(Args &&...args) requires std::is_constructible_v<V, Args...> {
    V val{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    return insert_value(std::move(val));
  }

  template <typename T>
  auto &operator[](T &&raw_key) requires(!is_set_ && !AllowDup) {
    if (root_->is_full()) {
      // if root is full then make it as a child of the new root
      auto new_root = std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_, false);
      root_->parent_ = new_root.get();
      new_root->size_ = root_->size_;
      new_root->height_ = root_->height_ + 1;
      new_root->children_.reserve(new_root->fanout() * 2);
      new_root->children_.push_back(std::move(root_));
      root_ = std::move(new_root);
      // and split
      split_child(root_->children_[0].get());
    }

    K key{std::forward<T>(raw_key)};
    auto x = root_.get();
    while (true) {
      auto i = std::distance(
          x->keys_.begin(),
          std::ranges::lower_bound(x->keys_, key, Comp{}, Proj{}));
      if (i < std::ssize(x->keys_) && key == Proj{}(x->keys_[i])) {
        return iterator_type(x, i)->second;
      } else if (x->is_leaf()) {
        V val{std::move(key), {}};
        return insert_leaf(x, i, std::forward<V>(val))->second;
      } else {
        if (x->children_[i]->is_full()) {
          split_child(x->children_[i].get());
          if (Comp{}(Proj{}(x->keys_[i]), key)) {
            ++i;
          }
        }
        x = x->children_[i].get();
      }
    }
  }

public:
  iterator_type erase(iterator_type iter) {
    if (iter == end()) {
      throw std::invalid_argument("attempt to erase end()");
    }
    auto node = iter.node_;
    std::vector<index_t> hints;
    hints.push_back(iter.index_);
    while (node && node->parent_) {
      hints.push_back(node->index_);
      node = node->parent_;
    }
    V value(std::move(*iter));
    return erase_hint(value, hints);
  }

  size_type erase(const K &key) {
    if constexpr (AllowDup) {
      return erase_range(iterator_type(find_lower_bound(key)),
                         iterator_type(find_upper_bound(key)));
    } else {
      return erase_lb(root_.get(), key);
    }
  }

  template <typename Pred> size_type erase_if(Pred pred) {
    auto old_size = size();
    auto it = begin_;
    for (; it != end();) {
      if (pred(*it)) {
        it = erase(it);
      } else {
        ++it;
      }
    }
    return old_size - size();
  }

  template <Containable K_, typename V_, index_t Fanout_, index_t FanoutLeaf_,
            typename Comp_, bool AllowDup_, typename Alloc_, typename T>
  friend BTreeBase<K_, V_, Fanout_, FanoutLeaf_, Comp_, AllowDup_, Alloc_>
  join(BTreeBase<K_, V_, Fanout_, FanoutLeaf_, Comp_, AllowDup_, Alloc_>
           &&tree_left,
       T &&raw_value,
       BTreeBase<K_, V_, Fanout_, FanoutLeaf_, Comp_, AllowDup_, Alloc_>
           &&tree_right) requires
      std::is_constructible_v<V_, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

  template <Containable K_, typename V_, index_t Fanout_, index_t FanoutLeaf_,
            typename Comp_, bool AllowDup_, typename Alloc_, typename T>
  friend std::pair<
      BTreeBase<K_, V_, Fanout_, FanoutLeaf_, Comp_, AllowDup_, Alloc_>,
      BTreeBase<K_, V_, Fanout_, FanoutLeaf_, Comp_, AllowDup_, Alloc_>>
  split(
      BTreeBase<K_, V_, Fanout_, FanoutLeaf_, Comp_, AllowDup_, Alloc_> &&tree,
      T &&raw_value) requires
      std::is_constructible_v<V_, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const BTreeBase &tree) {
    auto print = [&]() {
      if constexpr (is_set_) {
        for (const auto &v : tree) {
          os << v << ' ';
        }
      } else {
        for (const auto &[k, v] : tree) {
          os << '{' << k << ',' << v << '}';
        }
      }
    };
    print();
    return os;
  }
};

template <Containable K, typename V, index_t Fanout, index_t FanoutLeaf,
          typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename Alloc, typename T>
BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>
join(BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc> &&tree_left,
     T &&raw_value,
     BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>
         &&tree_right) requires
    std::is_constructible_v<V, std::remove_cvref_t<T>> {
  using Tree = BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>;
  using Node = Tree::node_type;
  using Proj = Tree::Proj;

  V mid_value{std::forward<T>(raw_value)};
  assert(tree_left.empty() ||
         !Comp{}(Proj{}(mid_value), Proj{}(*tree_left.crbegin())));
  assert(tree_right.empty() ||
         !Comp{}(Proj{}(*tree_right.cbegin()), Proj{}(mid_value)));
  assert(tree_left.alloc_ == tree_right.alloc_);

  auto height_left = tree_left.root_->height_;
  auto height_right = tree_right.root_->height_;
  auto size_left = tree_left.root_->size_;
  auto size_right = tree_right.root_->size_;

  if (height_left >= height_right) {
    Tree new_tree = std::move(tree_left);
    attr_t curr_height = height_left;
    Node *curr = new_tree.root_.get();
    if (new_tree.root_->is_full()) {
      // if root is full then make it as a child of the new root
      auto new_root = std::make_unique<Node>(new_tree.alloc_, false);
      new_tree.root_->index_ = 0;
      new_tree.root_->parent_ = new_root.get();
      new_root->size_ = new_tree.root_->size_;
      new_root->height_ = new_tree.root_->height_ + 1;
      new_root->children_.reserve(new_root->fanout() * 2);
      new_root->children_.push_back(std::move(new_tree.root_));
      new_tree.root_ = std::move(new_root);
      // and split
      new_tree.split_child(new_tree.root_->children_[0].get());
      curr = new_tree.root_->children_[1].get();
    }
    assert(curr->height_ == height_left);

    while (curr && curr_height > height_right) {
      assert(!curr->is_leaf());
      curr_height--;

      if (curr->children_.back()->is_full()) {
        new_tree.split_child(curr->children_.back().get());
      }
      curr = curr->children_.back().get();
    }
    assert(curr_height == height_right);
    auto parent = curr->parent_;
    if (!parent) {
      // tree_left was empty or height of two trees were the same
      auto new_root = std::make_unique<Node>(tree_left.alloc_);
      new_root->height_ = new_tree.root_->height_ + 1;

      new_root->keys_.push_back(std::move(mid_value));

      new_root->children_.reserve(new_root->fanout() * 2);

      new_tree.root_->parent_ = new_root.get();
      new_tree.root_->index_ = 0;
      new_root->children_.push_back(std::move(new_tree.root_));

      tree_right.root_->parent_ = new_root.get();
      tree_right.root_->index_ = 1;
      new_root->children_.push_back(std::move(tree_right.root_));

      new_tree.root_ = std::move(new_root);
      new_tree.try_merge(new_tree.root_.get(), false);
      new_tree.promote_root_if_necessary();
      new_tree.root_->size_ = size_left + size_right + 1;
    } else {
      parent->keys_.push_back(std::move(mid_value));

      tree_right.root_->parent_ = parent;
      tree_right.root_->index_ = std::ssize(parent->children_);
      parent->children_.push_back(std::move(tree_right.root_));

      while (parent) {
        parent->size_ += (size_right + 1);
        new_tree.try_merge(parent, false);
        parent = parent->parent_;
      }
      new_tree.promote_root_if_necessary();
    }
    assert(new_tree.root_->size_ == size_left + size_right + 1);
    assert(new_tree.verify());
    return new_tree;
  } else {
    Tree new_tree = std::move(tree_right);
    attr_t curr_height = height_right;
    Node *curr = new_tree.root_.get();
    if (new_tree.root_->is_full()) {
      // if root is full then make it as a child of the new root
      auto new_root = std::make_unique<Node>(new_tree.alloc_, false);
      new_tree.root_->index_ = 0;
      new_tree.root_->parent_ = new_root.get();
      new_root->size_ = new_tree.root_->size_;
      new_root->height_ = new_tree.root_->height_ + 1;
      new_root->children_.reserve(new_root->fanout() * 2);
      new_root->children_.push_back(std::move(new_tree.root_));
      new_tree.root_ = std::move(new_root);
      // and split
      new_tree.split_child(new_tree.root_->children_[0].get());
      curr = new_tree.root_->children_[0].get();
    }
    assert(curr->height_ == height_right);

    while (curr && curr_height > height_left) {
      assert(!curr->is_leaf());
      curr_height--;

      if (curr->children_.front()->is_full()) {
        new_tree.split_child(curr->children_[0].get());
      }
      curr = curr->children_.front().get();
    }
    assert(curr_height == height_left);
    auto parent = curr->parent_;
    assert(parent);
    parent->keys_.insert(parent->keys_.begin(), std::move(mid_value));

    auto new_begin = tree_left.begin();
    tree_left.root_->parent_ = parent;
    tree_left.root_->index_ = 0;
    parent->children_.insert(parent->children_.begin(),
                             std::move(tree_left.root_));
    for (auto &&child : parent->children_ | std::views::drop(1)) {
      child->index_++;
    }
    while (parent) {
      parent->size_ += (size_left + 1);
      new_tree.try_merge(parent, true);
      parent = parent->parent_;
    }
    new_tree.promote_root_if_necessary();
    new_tree.begin_ = new_begin;
    assert(new_tree.root_->size_ == size_left + size_right + 1);
    assert(new_tree.verify());
    return new_tree;
  }
}

template <Containable K, typename V, index_t Fanout, index_t FanoutLeaf,
          typename Comp, bool AllowDup, typename Alloc, typename T>
std::pair<BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>,
          BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>>
split(
    BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc> &&tree,
    T &&raw_value) requires std::is_constructible_v<V, std::remove_cvref_t<T>> {
  using Tree = BTreeBase<K, V, Fanout, FanoutLeaf, Comp, AllowDup, Alloc>;
  using Node = Tree::node_type;
  using Proj = Tree::Proj;

  Tree tree_left(tree.alloc_);
  Tree tree_right(tree.alloc_);

  if (tree.empty()) {
    assert(tree.root_->size_ ==
           tree_left.root_->size_ + tree_right.root_->size_);
    return {std::move(tree_left), std::move(tree_right)};
  }

  V mid_value{std::forward<T>(raw_value)};

  auto x = tree.root_.get();

  std::vector<index_t> indices;
  while (x) {
    auto i = std::distance(
        x->keys_.begin(),
        std::ranges::lower_bound(x->keys_, mid_value, Comp{}, Proj{}));
    indices.push_back(i);
    if (x->is_leaf()) {
      break;
    } else {
      x = x->children_[i].get();
    }
  }

  while (!indices.empty()) {
    auto i = indices.back();
    indices.pop_back();

    auto lroot = tree_left.root_.get();
    auto rroot = tree_right.root_.get();

    if (x->is_leaf()) {
      assert(lroot->size_ == 0 && rroot->size_ == 0);

      if (i > 0) {
        // send left i keys to lroot
        std::ranges::move(x->keys_ | std::views::take(i),
                          std::back_inserter(lroot->keys_));
        lroot->size_ += i;
      }

      if (i + 1 < std::ssize(x->keys_)) {
        // send right n - (i + 1) keys to rroot
        std::ranges::move(x->keys_ | std::views::drop(i + 1),
                          std::back_inserter(rroot->keys_));
        rroot->size_ += std::ssize(x->keys_) - (i + 1);
      }

      x->keys_.clear();
      x = x->parent_;
    } else {
      if (i > 0) {
        Tree supertree_left(tree.alloc_);
        auto slroot = supertree_left.root_.get();
        // sltree takes left i - 1 keys, i children
        // middle key is key[i - 1]

        assert(slroot->size_ == 0);

        std::ranges::move(x->keys_ | std::views::take(i - 1),
                          std::back_inserter(slroot->keys_));
        slroot->size_ += (i - 1);

        slroot->children_.reserve(slroot->fanout() * 2);

        std::ranges::move(x->children_ | std::views::take(i),
                          std::back_inserter(slroot->children_));
        slroot->height_ = slroot->children_[0]->height_ + 1;
        for (auto &&sl_child : slroot->children_) {
          sl_child->parent_ = slroot;
          slroot->size_ += sl_child->size_;
        }

        supertree_left.promote_root_if_necessary();
        supertree_left.set_begin();

        Tree new_tree_left =
            join(std::move(supertree_left), std::move(x->keys_[i - 1]),
                 std::move(tree_left));
        tree_left = std::move(new_tree_left);
      }

      if (i + 1 < std::ssize(x->children_)) {
        Tree supertree_right(tree.alloc_);
        auto srroot = supertree_right.root_.get();
        // srtree takes right n - (i + 1) keys, n - (i + 1) children
        // middle key is key[i]

        assert(srroot->size_ == 0);

        std::ranges::move(x->keys_ | std::views::drop(i + 1),
                          std::back_inserter(srroot->keys_));
        srroot->size_ += (std::ssize(x->keys_) - (i + 1));

        srroot->children_.reserve(srroot->fanout() * 2);

        std::ranges::move(x->children_ | std::views::drop(i + 1),
                          std::back_inserter(srroot->children_));
        srroot->height_ = srroot->children_[0]->height_ + 1;
        index_t sr_index = 0;
        for (auto &&sr_child : srroot->children_) {
          sr_child->parent_ = srroot;
          sr_child->index_ = sr_index++;
          srroot->size_ += sr_child->size_;
        }

        supertree_right.promote_root_if_necessary();
        supertree_right.set_begin();

        Tree new_tree_right =
            join(std::move(tree_right), std::move(x->keys_[i]),
                 std::move(supertree_right));
        tree_right = std::move(new_tree_right);
      }

      x->keys_.clear();
      x->children_.clear();
      x = x->parent_;
    }
  }

  assert(!x && indices.empty());
  assert(tree_left.verify());
  assert(tree_right.verify());
  assert(tree.root_->size_ ==
             tree_left.root_->size_ + tree_right.root_->size_ ||
         tree.root_->size_ ==
             tree_left.root_->size_ + tree_right.root_->size_ + 1);

  return {std::move(tree_left), std::move(tree_right)};
}

template <Containable K, index_t t = 2, index_t t_leaf = 2,
          typename Comp = std::ranges::less, typename Alloc = std::allocator<K>>
using BTreeSet = BTreeBase<K, K, t, t_leaf, Comp, false, Alloc>;

template <Containable K, index_t t = 2, index_t t_leaf = 2,
          typename Comp = std::ranges::less, typename Alloc = std::allocator<K>>
using BTreeMultiSet = BTreeBase<K, K, t, t_leaf, Comp, true, Alloc>;

template <Containable K, Containable V, index_t t = 2, index_t t_leaf = 2,
          typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<K, V>>>
using BTreeMap = BTreeBase<K, std::pair<K, V>, t, t_leaf, Comp, false, Alloc>;

template <Containable K, Containable V, index_t t = 2, index_t t_leaf = 2,
          typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<K, V>>>
using BTreeMultiMap =
    BTreeBase<K, std::pair<K, V>, t, t_leaf, Comp, true, Alloc>;

} // namespace frozenca

#endif //__FC_BTREE_H__
```

Using a performance test code (test/perftest.cpp) that insert/retrieve/erase 10 million `std::int64_t` in random order, I see the following results in my machine (gcc 11.2-O3):

```
Balanced tree test
Warming up complete...
frozenca::DiskBTreeSet test
Time to insert 10000000 elements: 5165.81 ms
Time to lookup 10000000 elements: 4784.74 ms
Time to erase 10000000 elements: 6180.8 ms
std::set test
Time to insert 10000000 elements: 12889.7 ms
Time to lookup 10000000 elements: 15527.5 ms
Time to erase 10000000 elements: 18128.5 ms
```

Comment: There are some bugs in this code that prevent it from being compiled, in particular if you clone a tree. I also see the code on your GitHub repository has changed significantly, so I suggest you either delete this post or update it to match your current version, if you still want it reviewed?